# TextWrangler show Folder path

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, ide, textwrangler

I'm new into TextWrangler. I'd like to let view a sidebar like on the following picture. (Which shows the folder path with included documents) Without knowing the name of this item, I don't know how to find it in the manual or in the menu for enabling it. 
[image]

Now my question: Where in the menu can I find this option?

Answer (score 5):

*View -> Go Here in Disk Browser* or, if you have more than one file open, and you're looking at the sidebar, the same "Go Here.." is available under the gear icon.

Answer (score 0):

Also `File` → `New…` → `Disk Browser` <kbd>⌥⌘</kbd> gives you a new window with Disk Browser sidebar starting from your home directory.